# Mercurial repository internal format

Tags: mercurial, internals

Docs regarding repository format over at [Mercurial site](https://www.mercurial-scm.org) are scattered all over and refer to various legacy versions as well as current one and all in all aren't very detailed IMO.

Is there any comprehensive and up-to-date description of Mercurial repository format?

*One Year Later*

[HgSharp](https://bitbucket.org/hglab/hgsharp/wiki/Home): 100% binary-compatible Mercurial Core implemented in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[Design page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Design)** at least references the relevant wiki pages.
It is indeed scattered, but it is listed in that page.

```
   .--------linkrev-------------.
   v                            |
.---------.    .--------.    .--------.
|changeset| .->|manifest| .->|file    |---.
|index    | |  |index   | |  |index   |   |--.
`---------' |  `--------' |  `--------'   |  |
    |       |      |      |     | `-------'  |
    V       |      V      |     V    `-------'
.---------. |  .--------. |  .---------.
|changeset|-'  |manifest|-'  |file     |
|data     |    |data    |    |revision |
`---------'    `--------'    `---------'
```

Comment: server not found 2016-08-29

Comment: @richard Thank you. I have restored the proper link.

Answer (score 4):

The design of Mercurial is described in [The Architecture of
Open Source Applications - Chapter 12. Mercurial](http://www.aosabook.org/en/mercurial.html).